# iphone easy oauth

Tags: iphone, oauth

I'm trying to use the OAuthConsumer library for iPhone to post tweets. I have done the same thing on Android with the following procedure:
1. Get request token
2. Show webview asking for authorisation and let the user authenticate
3. Capture callback request URL and take out the oauth_token and oauth_verifier.
4. Use the oauth_token to sign a HTTP post to update the user status.

I can get steps 1-3 to work on the iphone but have no idea how I use the token I get back to sign my post. All the examples I have found are using a PIN, is this the only way I can get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a custom scheme in the callback URL to restart your app.

Or http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth/ is a drop-in OAuth client implementation for iOS and Mac OS X